# Crossreferencing verbatim

Tags: cross-referencing, packages, verbatim

I am currently trying to reference a vebatim block, but aren't sure why this is not work...

```
\begin{verbatim}
ref: 
hyp:    
\label{verb:deletion}
\end{verbatim}
```

Edit

I guess it not possible to do this with verbatim.. 
I wanted to highlight a feature in the verbatim block, but can this be done in a different way such that it also can be referenced.

It would be appreciated if the solution would not involve messing with current commands, or creating new ones.  Isn't there a already a package capable of doing this?

Comment: verbatim='write literally', i.e. the commands are meaningless text to LaTeX, not commands to be expanded

Comment: What should `\ref{verb:deletion}` print and/or how is the `verbatim` environment numbered?

Comment: Since `verbatim` blocks are not numbered, what exactly are you hoping to remember with the label?

Comment: I guess i am not able to use verbatim.. that output something in a similar format, but where it is possible to put a label on it..

Comment: @dfh: Are you looking for something like displaying programming code? Then `listings` or `minted` are the alternatives, in my point of view, or `tcolorbox` and its verbatim box features!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{beramono}    
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=verb1,caption=First verbatim,float,frame=tb]
Foo stuff to be displayed verbatim

Something like \LaTeXe
\end{lstlisting}

In~\ref{verb1} we see some verbatim code
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this much better..  I is possible to center in the text in the listing?

Comment: no, not in an easy way. You can get the caption on the left. That is easy.

Answer (score 5):

Since the `verbatim` environment does not have a counter itself (at least in the `verbatim` package version), a `\label` does not have the intended effect, apart from the fact that `\label` appearing inside of the `verbatim` environment is totally ignored as a command sequence and being treated as pure text, having no further meaning.

However, it is possible to 'trick' the `verbatim` environment using a counter and having some kind of a lead-in line, displaying the number, in this case, a reference to the 'correct' number is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{myverb}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{%
\refstepcounter{myverb}%
\noindent\textbf{Verbatim stuff \themyverb}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Foo stuff to be displayed verbatim

Something like \LaTeXe
\end{verbatim}
\label{Foo}

In \ref{Foo} we see some foo stuff, but not \LaTeXe\ as expected!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to place the Verbatim stuff text somewhere?

Comment: Possibly like in equation?

Comment: @dfh: Well, yes, as long it is either before or after the environment

Comment: How do i move the text?

Comment: so the number is to the side and not at the top..

Comment: @dfh: No, not this way -- that was not in your 'request' of the post